# Problem pulling values from Arduino to Python

Tags: python, arduino

I wrote a program in Python which pulls values from Arduino. However, when I have the GUI window up, Python can’t read the values from Arduino, and nothing happens on the GUI window. If I remove the code containing the GUI window, the program works and can pull the values from Arduino. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
import serial  # 引用pySerial模組
from os import close
from tkinter.font import Font
#from bluetooth.widcomm import stop_advertising
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM
#from typing import Text#假設tk=tkinter
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



COM_PORT = 'COM7'    # 指定通訊埠名稱
BAUD_RATES = 9600    # 設定傳輸速率
ser = serial.Serial(COM_PORT, BAUD_RATES)   # 初始化序列通訊埠
while True:
        win=Tk()#建立視窗
        win.title("點餐系統")#標題
        win.geometry("1540x1050")#寬X高
        win.maxsize(width=1520,height=1050)
        img1=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\大麥克.png")
        img2=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\勁辣雞腿堡.png")
        img3=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\雙層吉事堡.png")
        img4=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\蕈菇黑牛堡.png")
        print('aaa')
        a='aaa'
        btn=Button(text="雙層吉事堡")
        btn.config(width=400,height=300)
        btn.config(image=img3)
        btn.place(x=300,y=480)
        lb3=Label(fg="black",text="三號餐",font='30')
        lb3.place(x=475,y=450) 
        while ser.in_waiting:          # 若收到序列資料…
                 data_raw= ser.readline()  # 讀取一行
                 data= data_raw.decode()   # 用預設的UTF-8解碼
                 print('接收到的原始資料：', data_raw)
                 print('接收到的資料：', data)
        if(bytes(data)=="solar1low"):
                    print('接收到的原始資料：', data_raw)
                    print('接收到的資料：', data)
                    win.destroy()#關閉舊視窗
                    win2=Tk()
                    win2.title("點餐系統")
                    win2.geometry("1540x1050")
                    image3=Image.open("D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\雙層吉事堡.png")
                    雙層吉事堡=ImageTk.PhotoImage (image3)
                    labelnext1=tkinter.Label(image=雙層吉事堡)
                    labelnext1.image=雙層吉事堡
                    labelnext1.config(width=650,height=650)
                    labelnext1.place(x=450,y=100)
                    btnnext1=Button(win2,text="確認餐點",fg='black',font='500',)
                    btnnext1.place(x=1400,y=700)
                    btnnext2=Button(win2,text="取消",fg='black',font='500')
                    btnnext2.place(x=1300,y=700)
                    lbnext2=Label(win2,fg="black",text="三號餐 100元",font='30')
                    lbnext2.place(x=700,y=50)
                    win2.mainloop()#常駐主視窗
        win.mainloop()#常駐主視窗
```

Comment: You need to refresh often.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code should look like:

```
import serial  # 引用pySerial模組
from os import close
from tkinter.font import Font
#from bluetooth.widcomm import stop_advertising
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM
#from typing import Text#假設tk=tkinter
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



COM_PORT = 'COM7'    # 指定通訊埠名稱
BAUD_RATES = 9600    # 設定傳輸速率
ser = serial.Serial(COM_PORT, BAUD_RATES)   # 初始化序列通訊埠
while True:
        win=Tk()#建立視窗
        win.title("點餐系統")#標題
        win.geometry("1540x1050")#寬X高
        win.maxsize(width=1520,height=1050)
        img1=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\大麥克.png")
        img2=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\勁辣雞腿堡.png")
        img3=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\雙層吉事堡.png")
        img4=PhotoImage(file="D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\蕈菇黑牛堡.png")
        print('aaa')
        a='aaa'
        btn=Button(text="雙層吉事堡")
        btn.config(width=400,height=300)
        btn.config(image=img3)
        btn.place(x=300,y=480)
        lb3=Label(fg="black",text="三號餐",font='30')
        lb3.place(x=475,y=450) 
        while ser.in_waiting:          # 若收到序列資料…
                    data_raw= ser.readline()  # 讀取一行
                    data= data_raw.decode()   # 用預設的UTF-8解碼
                    print('接收到的原始資料：', data_raw)
                    print('接收到的資料：', data)
        if(bytes(data)=="solar1low"):
                    print('接收到的原始資料：', data_raw)
                    print('接收到的資料：', data)
                    win.destroy()#關閉舊視窗
                    win2=Tk()
                    win2.title("點餐系統")
                    win2.geometry("1540x1050")
                    image3=Image.open("D:\PYTHON\PROJECT\雙層吉事堡.png")
                    雙層吉事堡=ImageTk.PhotoImage (image3)
                    labelnext1=tkinter.Label(image=雙層吉事堡)
                    labelnext1.image=雙層吉事堡
                    labelnext1.config(width=650,height=650)
                    labelnext1.place(x=450,y=100)
                    btnnext1=Button(win2,text="確認餐點",fg='black',font='500',)
                    btnnext1.place(x=1400,y=700)
                    btnnext2=Button(win2,text="取消",fg='black',font='500')
                    btnnext2.place(x=1300,y=700)
                    lbnext2=Label(win2,fg="black",text="三號餐 100元",font='30')
                    lbnext2.place(x=700,y=50)
                    win2.mainloop()#常駐主視窗
        win.update()
```

Notice how at the end I call `win.update()` instead of `win.mainloop()`. Running `win.update()` simply updates the window, and then moves on. Calling `win.mainloop()` blocks your code from running until the window is closed.

If you are still having trouble, try repacing `win2.mainloop()` with `win2.update()` as well.